# Meaning/purpose of AT+CGNSCMD command

Tags: gps, at-command

What AT+CGNSCMD command do? in the user manual, it say "Send command to GNSS" is it mean send command to GNSS system or somethig else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AT+CGNSCMD is an AT command which takes two arguments, and sends a **PMTK** command to the chip.

1. The first argument will be 0 (string) or 1 (hexadecimal) meaning the format of the char array which follows (second argument).
2. The second argument is going to be a "PMTK" command, which is compatible with the SIM808 GNSS decoder, in either char array or hex array format.

A typical useful example could be changing the NMEA string (GPS Data) update rate (PMTK command **type 220**).
To see it in action, first set the test mode on (which streams all the updates through UART to the serial monitor) with this AT command:

```
AT+CGNSTST = 1
```

now sending the following PMTK command (through the stated AT coomand) we will change the interval between updates to 200ms:

```
 AT+CGNSCMD=0,"$PMTK220,200*2C"
```

---

Many more useful PMTK commands can be found on [this pdf file](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PMTK_A11.pdf). Still, **be careful**, I don't know which commands will be compatible with your chip!